Databricks dashboard - Failed to execute query: Missing required fields
I am creating a databricks dashboard using a streaming delta live table. I am using an sql query to generate the dashboard. The dashboard was working fine, but after some time, it stopped working and I am getting following error:
Failed to execute query: Missing required fields: queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function, queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function, queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function, queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function, queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function, queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function, queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function, queries.query_context.predicate_groups.predicates.expression.call_expr.args.call_expr.args.call_expr.function

I am running a simple SQL query for the data:
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM col1-col2) AS diff_1,
    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM col1-col3) AS diff_2
 FROM 
    catalog.schema.table1; 

I can run the SQL query in the Data section and it is running fine. And if I create a new dashboard and use the same table, it is again working fine and data is displayed in dashboard. It is only in the existing dashboard where I am facing issues. Can someone help me why I have this error in the existing dashboard?

-Did anything changed recently with respect to the tables in terms of permissions etc?
-Can you try clearing cache and refresh the dashboard?

No nothing has changed. If I open another page on the dashboard, I can create graphs from the same dataset which I am using on the existing page.

Start with col1-col2-. When it works, do extract.

@DumbCoder Are you using Azure databricks by any chance? and have you tried in spark.sql?
